# Is it possible to destructure and type a function param object with known properties?

Tags: typescript, parameters, destructuring

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gQgKQKIGEAqB9ACgQQEo4CyUAvFAN4BQUUYAhsABYB2dAthAFxQDOwATgEtmAcwA01KPwD2AV2AQsDRtz5DRlAL6VKEAB5hp-YFADG05nygiIwAMoAbWSMINTjUlAAUYGWB7c8Mjo2PhEAJSUqgLCIqQAfBSSNOaWJuS0yqwcYlJyCkpMUJqevtL+ANzJUray-MxQAER2MIRIGHYAMgCqAOKNWlW6BkYmqVY29k4ubowYAGoATJ5e5PRM2Vy8MaK5MvKKytHqIprhx7EJSTQ0-LX1TS1tHT39g0A)

Use case: function that gets a single object with known properties. Need to destructure and assign at the same time.

This works:

```
type OBJECT_PARAM = {
  pathname: string,
  routePath: string
}

export const getSlugMatch = (props: OBJECT_PARAM)
: string => {
    const { pathname, routePath } = props;
    return "SOME_SLUG"
};
```

This **doesn't** work:

```
export const getSlugMatch_V2 = ({pathname: string, routePath: string}): string => {
    return "SOME_SLUG"
};
```

[image]

Is there any way around this? How do people usually handle this? Do I really need to define the `OBJECT_PARAM`?

I guess that it does not work because it conflicts with Javascript way of renaming destructured properties. What is the best workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructuring needs to be separate from the type since, like you said, the property colon syntax is already used for renaming.  The best you can do is to declare the type inline:

```
export const getSlugMatch_V2 = ({pathname, routePath}: {pathname: string, routePath: string}): string => {
    return "SOME_SLUG"
};
```